# Reset permissions for iOS apps installed on Apple Silicon Mac

Tags: ios, avfoundation, apple-silicon, avcapture, xcode14

UI flows can be built around requesting permissions for, for example, camera or microphone access in iOS apps. With Xcode 14, it's super easy to run an app on an Apple Silicon Mac with the device "My Mac (Designed for iPhone)". However, how do you reset camera permissions to new install state for an iOS app installed and run that way on Mac?

Naturally, removing the app from the Products folder does not remove its row in Settings -> Security and Privacy -> Camera on MacOS and disabling camera access via that row sets `AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus` to `denied` and not `notDetermined` even with a fresh install.